# XSTL/ XSL file: need to remove duplicates generically from the parent tag given that all the child key values are same for XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have been working on a problem for a long time. I need to remove duplicates from xml file based on the key value of the child tag. The parent tag "A" will always be known and will stay the same. The nested tags can have different names i.e., there could be "Name", "Location", "Name". If the data under 2 "Name" tags are duplicates of each other, one of the name tag along with its child nodes must get removed. This should only happen if all the child tag key values are same and not if only one or 2 or more tags are same but there exists some tags with different key value or same key and different value under the parent tag.

Example:

```
`<A>
  <Name>
  <c>1<c>
  <d>g</d>
  <e>h</e>
 </Name>
 <Location>
  <c>2<c>
  <d>g</d>
  <e>h</e>
 </Location>
 <Name>
  <c>1<c>
  <d>g</d>
  <e>h</e>
 </Name>
<A>`
```

Expected output:

```
`<A>
 <Name>
  <c>1<c>
  <d>g</d>
  <e>h</e>
 </Name>
 <Locaiton>
  <c>2<c>
  <d>g</d>
  <e>h</e>
 </Locaiton>
<A>`
```

I tried : this:

```
`<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:if test="not(node()) or not(preceding-sibling::node()[.=string(current())])">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:if>
```

</xsl:template>`

but what ended up happening was that the child tags with the same key values got removed as well and I was getting something like this:

```
`<A>
 <Name>
     <c>1<c>
     <d>g</d>
     <e>h</e>
</Name>
<Location>
    <c>2<c>

</Location>
<A>`
```

I'm looking for a generic way as I don't want to specify the tag values or keys in the file.

Thanks in advance :)!

Comment: Which version of XSLT?

Comment: The one above is utilizing 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 3 using a composite key with `for-each-group group-by` might suffice:

```
  <xsl:template match="A">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" composite="yes" group-by="*">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

If the grandchildren also not to be sorted then you might need

```
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" composite="yes" group-by="sort(*, (), function($c) { name($c) })">
```

instead of the simple group-by given above.

Both ways, as the base transformation, you need to set up the identity transformation by declaring `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` as a child of `xsl:stylesheet` (or `xsl:transform`) in the XSLT.

But the problem is rather underspecified, it is not clear whether the names and order of child elements are simply unknown are always the same or whether there can be variations and how to handle them.

As an alternative, if you can have different elements as children of `A` but need to eliminate duplicates only for a specific one like `B` but for possible other elements then a key explicitly declared for `B` elements can help

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="B-group" match="A/B" use="sort(*, (), function($c) { name($c) })"/>

  <xsl:template match="B[not(. is key('B-group', sort(*, (), function($c) { name($c) }))[1])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The order of childs and names will always be unknown. The items can appear in any order and can contain any data. Have to make sure that in the XML file, if there are 2 parents tags with exactly the same child key values, one of the entire parent tag must be removed along with its child nodes.

Comment: Also, please note that the name of the tags could be anything other than the top xml tag such that "A" will be there but tags "B" or "c" or "d" could be anything like "b" could be "names" and so on

Comment: I'm new to XSTL and have knowledge about it. Got this after running above XSTL 3:                                                             ERROR:  'Unsupported XSL element 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:for-each-group''
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported XSL element 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform:for-each-group'
        at

Comment: Well, to use XSLT 3 you need to use an XSLT 3 processor, in the Java world that means putting Saxon 10 or 9.9 or 9.8 on the class path.

Comment: And it would help if you edited your question and somehow detail the kind of input you can have, it is not clear what "can contain any data" means, for example, if the grandchildren you call keys can have further element content or only plain text. It is also not clear whether the children of `A` will all have the same name (even if it is unknown) or whether there can be children of different names and any deduplication needs to take the element name into account as well.

Comment: Ran it, it got rid of all the tags other than "A" and only values are left behind for the rest.

Comment: @sks, well, that template tries to take care of the identification and elimination of duplicates, for the rest you need the identity transformation you can declare as I have shown in the edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martin. It got the job done and works like a charm. :)